# Alterando Rotas com Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando alterar uma rota no meu projeto, o controle é assim:

```
 public class TagController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Tag

        private MYEntities db = new MYEntities ();

        [Route("tags")]
        [OutputCache(Duration = 36000, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var t = db.TAGs.OrderBy(p => p.DESCRIPTION);

            return View(t.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Quando eu executo a URL:

```
http://localhost:7071/tags
```

Ele retorna o erro:

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Não é possível encontrar o recurso.
>
> Descrição: HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando (ou uma de
> suas dependências) não pôde ser removido, seu nome foi alterado ou
> está temporariamente indisponível. Examine o URL e certifique-se de
> que está digitado corretamente.
>
> URL solicitada: /tags
>
> Informações sobre a Versão: Microsoft .NET Framework Versão:4.0.30319;
> Versão do ASP.NET:4.0.30319.34248

Alteração:

```
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Categoria", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Existe uma view `Index.cshtml` dentro da pasta `Tag` dentro da pasta `Views`, acredito que não seja problema da view não existir e sim da rota não está funcionando.

Outra coisa é que se rodar com:

```
http://localhost:7071/Tag/Index
```

Também da erro dizendo que não existe `/Tag/Index`

Tirando a anotação `[Route("tags")]` do método `Index` ele funciona com a URL acima.

Adicionei o seguinte codigo ao RouteConfig, mas não funcionou:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "teste",
                url: "tags",
                defaults: new { controller = "Tag", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Gostaria de usar o `Route[("tags")]` como monstra esse [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Comment: Só de olhar, talvez já vi o erro... Você declarou essa rota que você ta tentando acessar ? No RoutesConfig mesmo... E se tentar acessar pela url: `http://localhost:7071/Index`, funciona ?

Comment: Coloquei mais informações sobre o problema, o `RouteConfig` não foi alterado, é uma aplicação de coisa controles, não alterei praticamente nada de configuração.

Comment: Então talvez seja esse o problema... O asp.net mvc reconhece somente as rotas que são declaradas e configuradas no routes... Tente adicionar uma nova rota no arquivo routes, um copia e cola mesmo, em baixo da rota padrão, se funcionar a gente põe como resposta.

Comment: Adicionei outra rota, não funcionou, coloquei mais informações na pergunta

Comment: E assim [Route("/Tags/Index")] ?

Comment: Não foi, a impressão que dá é que o Route não funciona.

Comment: Tenta só comentar essa rota padrão e deixar só a sua pra ver...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para utilizar o *attribute based routing*, precisas de chamar o metodo `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` (para Web API 2) ou `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` (para MVC):

```
 config.routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Isto vai inspeccionar os atributos em todos os controllers/accoes e configurar as suas rotas.

No final, o metodo `RegisterRoutes` deve ficar assim:

```
//RouteConfig.cs
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        // Attribute routing.     
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    }
}

//WebApiConfig.cs
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Mais informacao:

- [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
- [Enabling Attribute Routing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#enabling-attribute-routing)